# Difference between `PlutusTx.TH.compile` and `PlutusTx.compile`?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutustx

I've been reading the official Plutus docs and saw that in the explanation about Template Haskell, there is information about `PlutusTx.TH.compile`, to use it for producing the quoted Plutus Core program.

And in Plutus-Pioneers examples there is `PlutusTx.compile` being used, instead of the 'TH' version.

Can this two imported functions be used interchangeably? Their type looks the same in ghci, so I'm a bit confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hi man Lars answered this in the 7th Q&A video of the Plutus pioneers program cohort 3.

If you don't want to watch the video the long and short of it is that the `PlutusTx.TH.compile` module is just an Exported version of the  `PlutusTx.compile` module. This is done to make it easier for people to use, but the `PlutusTx.compile` is really all you need and you should learn it just in case at some point the `PlutusTx.compile` module has some functionality that has yet to be exported to the `PlutusTx.TH.compile` module.